# How to get DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries(of ???)) for a class known only on runtime

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using entity framework
I'm trying to make a general function that works for an object for which the class is know only on runtime.
I have an instruction that use an expression similar to this :

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries(of Myobj1)
```

Of course that if I know the class name "MyObj1" the above expression is working correctly.

But, at runtime , I only have an variable : **Dim tp as type** , which contain the class ,  and i need an expression like this :

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries(of tp)
```

Thank you !

Comment: Consider using `x => t.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())`, where  `t` is the **an object from a class** you described above.

Answer (score 1):

Assumes that `obj` is an instance of `MyObj1`, then you can do as:

```
DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.GetType() == obj.GetType())
```

Comment: If you also want to find out the instances of the subclasses of `MyObj1` not just `MyObj1` itself, using: `DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()))`

Comment: Sorry , the problem is that  I pass the expression above to a sub like this  : Public Sub Mysub(Of T As Class)(list1 As IEnumerable(Of DbEntityEntry(Of T)))when I try your solution and call this sub with this parameter : DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.GetType() == obj.GetType()) or this DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())), I get an error.

Comment: Yes , I have translated.

Comment: This is the error : Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Sub MySub(Of T As Class)(list1 As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry(Of T)))' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

Comment: If I call the sub , when I know the class like this : MySub(context.ChangeTracker.Entries(Of MyObj1) everything is ok. But i don't know the MyObj1 name , so i want a general expression like this , but for a variable type t.

Comment: According to the error message, maybe you should check out whether there is any Subs with the same name of `MySub`. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531243.aspx

Comment: The sub is this : .........Public Sub Mysub(Of T As Class)(list1 As IEnumerable(Of DbEntityEntry(Of T)))...... If i call for a known class like this : .......MySub(context.ChangeTracker.Entries(Of MyObj1))........ everything is ok. when i call with your expression , i get the error that i have described.

Comment: Therefore, you should use the base class of all possible classes which the object belongs to, like `EntityBase` or `IEntity`. If you have no idea about it on compile-time, using `System.Object` is the only way.

Comment: My original question was : How can i create an expression ....context.ChangeTracker.Entries(of ???) , for a general class , known only on runtime. so could you be more clear what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to only commit changes on specific class:

```
        public static void ResetDBContext(this DBcontext context, Type type )
        {
            var entries = context.ChangeTracker
                                 .Entries()
                                 .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged && e.Entity.GetType()==type)
                                 .ToArray();

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        entry.Reload();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

then pass your type to this function (with `obj.GetType()`)

Answer (score -1):

You can use System.Linq to make your life easier

If you have an instance of the object:

```
DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x == myObject)
```

If you only know the type during run-time

```
DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(MyObj1))
```

Else, if you want to check whether it 'is' a class:

```
DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x is MyObj1)
```

If you're dealing with a single object, you may use First/FirstOrDefault/Single/SingleOrDefault based on your preference and logic

Comment: Couldn't you just use the type or 'is' comparison as show in the comment? Is "class name" a string or object type or object instance?

Comment: This is wrong.  The questioner doesn't know the type name at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

```
DBcontext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity.GetType() == typeof(MyObj1))
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code. Also provide an explanation of what this code is doing.

Comment: @JonathanMee - that wouldn't help since the code is wrong on multiple levels anyway.

Comment: @hoodaticus Being wrong on multiple levels wouldn't have earned a flag from me. Being bare code did. Since I don't understand the code well enough to make a statement on it's validity I will also default to supporting your down-vote.